# Is it possible to filter Pandas DataFrame column if column is a list?

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd

dafr = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3], 'b': [[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[3,4,5]]})
```

I try to do something like:

```
dafr[dafr['b'].isin(2)]
```

which should return rows that has lists: [1,2,3] & [2,3,4].

I wonder if this is possible?

Comment: In general it is undesirable to store non-scalar values in pandas DataFrames. Perhaps there is a better way to construct the dataframe, or maybe dataframes are not the right storage for your data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`isin` returns whether the column value is in what you pass.  You want to check if what you pass is in the column value.

As far as I know there is no direct shortcut for this, but you can do it using `map`:

```
>>> dafr[dafr.b.map(lambda x: 2 in x)]
    a          b
0  1  [1, 2, 3]
1  2  [2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Accepted for appreciation of short explanation.

Answer (score 3):

```
dafr[dafr['b'].apply(lambda x: 2 in x)]
```

Comment: Kudos for fastest reply!

Answer (score 0):

If you stored b as column of tuples rather than column of lists, `afr[dafr['b'].apply(lambda x: 2 in x)]`
will execute quite fast.